# Plot mean of variables in two different dataframes and plot it in same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have two dataframes: dataframe5 and dataframe 6.

I have created a temporal plot for both of the dataframes in a single plot( Total vs Year)
I require to find the mean of these two lines and plot it in the same graph.[temporalplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjTiW.png)

My attempts have not been working so far

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- merge(dataframe5, dataframe6, by = 'Total')

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(Year.x, Total), color = '#0087E9', size = 5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = 'black', size = 16),
        axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'))
```

Note: Both of the dataframes consist of 88 observations

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dput(dataframe5)` and `dput(dataframe6)`? Or simply `dput(head(dataframe5))` for the two if the other is too much.

Comment: If it's really just 2 data frames, same rows, same columns, same order, and all your data is numeric, then by far the quickest solution is to use `df_mean = (dataframe5 + dataframe6) / 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general answer that will scale up to as many data frames as you have:

```
library(dplyr)
df_list = list(df5 = df5, df6 = df6)
library(dplyr)
big_df = bind_rows(df_list, .id = "source")
big_df = big_df %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarize_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%
  mutate(source = "Mean") %>%
  bind_rows(big_df)

ggplot(big_df, aes(x = Year, y = Total, color = source)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Naming the `list` more appropriately will help with the plot labels. If you do have more data frames, I'd strongly recommend reading my answer at [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Using this data:

```
df5 = read.table(text = "Year     VegC    LittC   SoilfC   SoilsC    Total
1 2013 1.820858 1.704079 4.544182 1.964507 10.03363
2 2014 1.813573 1.722106 4.548287 1.964658 10.04863
3 2015 1.776853 1.722110 4.553425 1.964817 10.01722
4 2016 1.794462 1.691728 4.556691 1.964973 10.00785
5 2017 1.808207 1.708956 4.557116 1.965063 10.03936
6 2018 1.831758 1.728973 4.559844 1.965192 10.08578",
header = T)

df6 = read.table(text =
" Year     VegC    LittC   SoilfC   SoilsC    Total
1 2013 1.832084 1.736137 4.542052 1.964454 10.07474
2 2014 1.806351 1.741353 4.548349 1.964633 10.06069
3 2015 1.825316 1.729084 4.552433 1.964792 10.07164
4 2016 1.845673 1.735861 4.553766 1.964900 10.10020
5 2017 1.810343 1.754477 4.556542 1.965033 10.08640
6 2018 1.814503 1.728337 4.561960 1.965191 10.07001",
header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you would like to plot for the year 2013 10,054185

If you have for every year one line you can create a new col and add this to your existing ggplot:

```
df <- dataframe5$Year
df$total5 <- dataframe5$Total
df$total6 <- dataframe6$Total
df$totalmean <- (df$total5+df$total6)/2
```

By plotting `df$totalmean` you should get the mean of the line. Just add the lines by `+ Geometrie_line(...)`in the existing ggplot.